# Is this a real chopper bike

Tags: frames

Could anyone confirm any information regarding this bike I've found please , it doesn't have the regular chopper gear placing but the body etc looks similar

Comment: Curious how you expect anyone to answer this question

Comment: What is "real" ?  Are you seeing an authentication or a philosophical answer ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  We can't give you any information unless you show us what you're talking about.  (And define your terms, as noted in the comments above.)

Comment: I can't help the impression that you intended to include photos but somehow they aren't showing.

Comment: Please use [edit] to insert photos of your bike into the question.  Without more info, this question risks being closed.   Another option is to search google images and find one that looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

"Chopper" is the name of a style of bike, as well as a specific model sold by Raleigh.

[image] 
 Full article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raleigh_Chopper on this specific brand/model

Any bike that has some of these features could be called a Chopper:

- A crank-forward position relative to the saddle
- A very-slack head-tube angle (a "lying down" or "about to break" look)
- A banana seat, or something motorbike-inspired
- Ape-hanger handlebars
- Long front forks perhaps with

  - a shallow angle
  - dual crowns
  - other motorcycle features
- Sometimes high-spoke count wheels
- A really wide rear tyre compared to the front

[image]

[image]